# My imenu-entries get double listed. How could I correct that?

Tags: ido, imenu, helm-sources

With the PHP-mode that's shipped with Emacs, suppose I have the following PHP function:

```
public function foo() 
{
    print "bar";
}
```

Imenu will list the `foo` in all methods and public methods.

Other packages like Helm and Ido use the same Imenu, which causes my functions to be double listed. When I call `helm-imenu` that uses the imenu source, I see my functions double listed.

It gets listed in helm-imenu as `All methods / foo` and `public methods / foo`. I see the same in ido-imenu. 
I would like to reduce that to only the methods get listed once, instead double. And in Emacs nearly everything is scriptable, right?

To make it more clear what I'm meaning, a screenshot:

[image]

Sometimes it makes it very confusing for me, when navigating around in the codebase.

So any suggestion how I could handle this?

Comment: You should add a link to the php mode you are using, because the solution depends on the way the imenu is created.

Comment: Do you mean the php-mode that's get shipped with Emacs?

Comment: php-mode does not ship with Emacs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vanilla imenu presents things hierarchically, so you'd first have to choose between Public/Private/All functions, before you actually chose from a list of actual function. However, this is confusing with other imenu frontends that show them all at the same time.

There are distinct entries in the `imenu-generic-expression` value that `php-mode` defines for private, protected, public, and all functions. You could remove the "all" entry or remove the private, protected, and public entries to make things appear once.

For example this will remove the "All Methods" category from `imenu` in `php-mode`.

```lisp
(with-eval-after-load "php-mode"
  (add-hook 'php-mode-hook
            (defun my-php-mode-hook ()
              (setq-local imenu-generic-expression
                    (cl-remove-if 
                     (lambda (entry) (equal (car entry) "All Methods"))
                     php-imenu-generic-expression)))))
```

You may want to look at the definition of `php-imenu-generic-expression` to better understand what the hook is doing.

Comment: You still amaze me with your solutions. I checked the documentation of imenu, but found nothing satisfying that addressed my issue. How did you find such ways to a solution? (As in, how do you knew the `php-imenu-generic-expression` was the key to this?)

Comment: `imenu-generic-expression` always drives imenu entries, so if `php-mode` supports imenu, it must customize `imenu-generic-expression`. So I opened `php-mode` and searched for `imenu-generic-expressions` to see what it sets the variable as.